# Loop code for URL is not working properly

Tags: python, loops, url, exit

So my code for the checking should be all right...

```
URL = "https://youtube.com/testingforthis"
s1 = url.startswith('https://')
s2 = url.startswith('http://')
if s1 == True or s2 == True:
  na = [':', '/', '.']
  for i in na:
    furl = url.replace(i, '')
  alphacheck = furl.isalnum()
  if alphacheck == True:
    ng = False
  else:
    ng = True
else:
  ng = True
```

But this loop is still activating for some reasons

```
if ng == True:
  print(url, "is not valid")
  exit(0)
```

If you run the code, it will crash. Why?

Comment: Please provide the imports and stack trace. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop:

```
  for i in na:
        furl = url.replace(i, '')
```

you keep replacing in the original URL, not the URL that contains the previous replacements. So the final value of `furl` just has the last replacement, not all the replacements.

You should assign the result of the replacement back to the same variable.

```
furl = url
for i in na:
    furl = furl.replace(i, '')
```